# How to change coordinates of integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there some built-in routine, some easier method to change variables of integration, without/before solving the integral?
Say I have

```
Integrate[expression1[x, y, z], x, y, z]
```

how to change it to

```
Integrate[expression2[r, theta, phi], r, theta, phi]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the specific example of Cartesian -> Spherical transformation, you could use

```
TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", expression1[x, y, z], {x,y,z} -> {r, theta, phi}] * 
  CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "MappingJacobianDeterminant"][{r, theta, phi}]
```

to get `expression2[r, theta, phi]`

Alternatively, you could use `CoordinateChartData["Spherical", "VolumeFactor"][{r, theta, phi}]` in the integral.

This functionality is new in version 9.  In version 8, you'd have to do the calculations by hand:

```
mapping = {x, y, z} -> {r Cos[phi] Sin[theta], r Sin[phi] Sin[theta], r Cos[theta]}
jd = Simplify@Det@D[mapping[[2]], {{r, theta, phi}}]

expression1[x, y, z] jd /. Thread[mapping]
```

Comment: This looks nice, but anything for ver. 8?

Comment: Ok, I can get around with JacobianDeterminant for now. I was just hoping there are some bulit-in routines, and it's true for ver. 9. Thanks

Comment: @Vladimir I don't think there are builtins for v8, see my update

Comment: @Szabolcs I see you were already talking about `JacobianDeterminant`, but I don't see it spelled out anywhere. So I added an answer containing that approach and a variation thereof.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, in version 8 (and version 9 too) you can load the `VectorAnalysis` package and do one of the following:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]

JacobianDeterminant[Spherical[r, θ, ϕ]]
(* ==> r^2 Sin[θ] *)

Times @@ ScaleFactors[Spherical[r, θ, ϕ]]
(* ==> r^2 Sin[θ] *)
```

So instead of invoking `JacobianDeterminant`, you can get the scale factors individually. The coordinates ($r$, $\theta$, $\phi$) in each case can be named as I did above - if you leave that out, it defaults to built-in capitalized standard names.

**Putting this into an integral**

To show that this leads to a syntax which is significantly more concise than the new version 9 syntax, see this specific integral. I define a function of `Cartesian` variables, then do the variable transformation in the integral, as was asked for in the question:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + 2 y + z

Integrate[
 f @@ CoordinatesToCartesian[#, Spherical @@ #] JacobianDeterminant[
     Spherical @@ #] &@{r, θ, ϕ},
 r, θ, ϕ]

(*
==> 
  -(1/8) r^4 (ϕ Cos[θ]^2 + θ (2 Cos[ϕ] - 
      Sin[ϕ]) + 
   Cos[θ] Sin[θ] (-2 Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ]))
*)
```

I honestly think this is much prettier than what you now have to write in version 9. But I also like the completely manual approach in Szabolcs' answer.

Comment: However, methods from "VectorAnalysis" are limited to 3D. This is why for ver. 8. I would even do explicit calculation, like Szabolcs.

Comment: Sure, but your example is also 3D. And the price you pay in version 9 is a much more lengthy syntax. I'll show the much more concise integration syntax for my approach in an edited answer.

Comment: I haven't used this package before. You're right that it is simpler than what v9 offers.  Maybe new Mma functions are getting a bit more wordy than they should be ...

Comment: @Jens Wow, these pure functions are powerful :)
Yes, I see what you mean!

Answer (score 4):

In *v13.1* [`IntegrateChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) is introduced:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][f[x, y, z], x, y, z], 
 {r, θ, ϕ}, "Cartesian" -> "Spherical"]
(* Inactive[Integrate][
     r^2 f[r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], r Cos[θ]] Sin[θ], 
     r, θ, ϕ, 
     Assumptions -> 
       x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && z ∈ Reals && 
       r > 0 && 0 < θ < π && -π < ϕ <= π] *)
```